# Keep url params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm pulling the following params:

```
<%= link_to "Sign up", new_store_registration_path(:plan_id => plan.id, :price => plan.price) %>
```

After registration I have set up to redirect to new_transaction_path

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  new_transaction_path(resource)
end
```

But when redirected to the new path the params don't appear. How can I show the two params on the new_transaction_path url??

Comment: You are adding parameters in a query string to a path that it's `new_store_registration`, but they won't be kept by the `after_sign_up_path_for ` method. One way could be to store them in a sessions (see [guidelines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#accessing-the-session)) when hitting the `new` action in the `store_registration` controller and then retrieve them in the `after_sign_up_path_for` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it but maybe this works:

In your controller

```
def new 
  session[:registration_params] = request.query_parameters
end
```

In your redirect method

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  new_transaction_path(resource, session[:registration_params])
end
```

Comment: maybe you can help me out with something else.  After the signup I would like to keep the `params[:email]` too and pass then to another page with `<%= hidden_field_tag(:email, params["email"]) %>`. Any idea on how I can do that???

Comment: It'd be best to open another question. Anyhow, if the user signs up you can retrieve the email from the database (which is my preferred option), otherwise you can store it in a `session` variable rather then a `params` one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in a controller to keep only certain params.

> @keep_params = params.permit(:start_date, :end_date)

then in the view:

> my_custom_path(@keep_params)